# Why Storyboard value wouldn't get from a resource or binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, resources, storyboard, dynamicresource

I have construction below and it works:

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="GrowOnStart">
   <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" Storyboard.TargetName="window">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1024"/>
```

Why it doesn't work if I try something like this:

```
  <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource StartingPositionLeft}"/>
```

And yes, I defined the resource before the storyboard.
And the statement like the next one wouldn't work either:

```
 <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding StartingPositionLeft}"/>
```

And yes it's a public property on code behind and **this.DataContext** set to **this**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Animations are freezable objects.  There is more information in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx), but basically it means you can't use binding because properties in the frozen object (i.e. the animation) cannot change.

To get around this limitation, you will need to do some or all of the work in code-behind.

Comment: Yeah, seems the only way through editing storyboard in code behind.

 var sb = (Storyboard)Resources["GrowOnStart"];
 var anim = (DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames)sb.Children[0];
 anim.KeyFrames[0].Value = 100;

Comment: In code behind, you should be able to get the value that you wanted to bind to (instead of doing hard-coded values).  For instance, using your examples, you can do something like anim.KeyFrames[0].Value = this.StartingPositionLeft (or whatever property you want to bind to), or you can use FindResource to find and get the value of whatever DynamicResource (or StaticResource) that you wanted to originally use.