# How to change EasingDoubleKeyFrame value at Runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, expression-blend

I am trying to make a *TranslateTransform* animation.  In the animation, I need my object to remain at the center of the window.  I know WPF animation is Freezable.  I am using a converter, but it initializes values at startup.  Is there any way to set the value of *EasingDoubleKeyFrame* at runtime?

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding Width, Converter={StaticResource Minus}, ElementName=grid}"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{Binding Width, Converter={StaticResource EnteringValueConverter}, ElementName=grid}"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an x:Name Attribute to the EasingDoubleKeyFrame Element.
Afterwards you should be able to access it via code:

x:Name="keyframe"

Then:

keyframe.SetValue(EasingDoubleKeyFrame.ValueProperty, yourValue);

Comment: I am add x:Name Attribute to the EasingDoubleKeyFrame Element but I can`t access it from code behind.
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="myEasingKey" KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="136"/>
There is nothing exist named   myEasingKey in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

"This is because Animations are freezable objects. There is more information in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx), but basically it means you can't use binding because properties in the frozen object (i.e. the animation) cannot change.

To get around this limitation, you will need to do some or all of the work in code-behind."

quote from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415094/why-storyboard-value-wouldnt-get-from-a-resource-or-binding)

Answer (score 0):

the `EasingDoubleKeyFrame` cannot be accessed via `x:Name` attribute. Instead you should use a different approach to define the `EasingDoubleKeyFrame` as `StaticResource` and link it via `ResourceKey` like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Key="myEasingKey" KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="136" />
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
             <StaticResource ResourceKey="myEasingKey" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Access the it via code behind like below:

```
(EasingDoubleKeyFrame)Resources["myEasingKey"].Value = X;
```

Hope this helps...